# Remove duplicated Java packages

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, package-management, java, duplicate

I'm on linux mint 12

I have installed Java, following the [NetBeans instructions](http://wiki.netbeans.org/InstallingNetbeansUbuntu7.04). It wasn't working on chrome, so I installed it like that:

```
sudo echo 'deb http://www.duinsoft.nl/pkg debs all' >> /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 5CB26B26
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install update-sun-jre
```

without uninstalling the other one, now I have 2 or 3 java on my PC, NetBeans is not running anymore and whenever I do `sudo apt-get update` I get warnings about dupes.
I just want to keep one Java which I have installed without following netbeans instructions, I'm going to uninstall NetBeans and use Eclipse.

**Fslint** is not finding the dupes, I don't why. I don't trust tools, I only trust terminal, so how to do it from there?

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps but you can choose default java through the following:
`sudo update-java-alternatives -l` lists all java versions. `sudo update-java-alternatives -s <your_choice>` will set it.

Comment: @Nunoxic when i run `sudo update-java-alternatives -l` I see `java-1.6.0-openjdk 1061 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk` that's strange! I'm sure that i installed jre! how to remove openjdk and clean everything up

Answer (score 0):

@dupes in apt: clean up your `/etc/apt/sources.list` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`

@duplicate java: make a `aptitude search openjdk | grep "i "` and `aptitude search java | grep "i "` and `apt-get delete` every package which belongs to a jre/jdk (openjdk, Oracle's Java etc. pp.)

With eclipse it should be enough to use the java version with is included in your distro.

Comment: Thanks, but what is wrong with my post?

Comment: Honestly, yes, it was already ok for me ;-) But ok, I escaped the commands and directories/files.